# How do I reverse the animation of an AnimatedSprite in AndEngine?

Tags: android, animation, sprite, andengine

I have an `AnimatedSprite` that after it finishes the animation I want to reverse animate it. I want to do that continuously. Once the reverse animation is complete I want to play the original one. This may be easy one but I am new to Android and AndEngine.

```
mFlower1Sprite = new AnimatedSprite(20, 800, this.mFlower1);
mFlower1Sprite.setScale((float) 1.5);

mFlower1Sprite.animate(500,  0, new IAnimationListener () {
    public void onAnimationEnd(final AnimatedSprite pAnimatedSprite) {
            // reverse animation
    }
});

mScene.attachChild(mFlower1Sprite);
return mScene;
```

Comment: you could try mFlower1.setFlippedHorizontal(true); It will flip the image so you will be starting with your last frame first, but it will also change the direction your sprite is facing. Just some ideas =)

Comment: the only method upto my knowledge is to use animate (long[] pFrameDurations, int[] pFrames, 
    int pLoopCount) method in which first you have to mention all the frames from starting to end followed by the reversal of the same.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any support to reverse the frames of an AnimatedSprite, although it's probably a useful feature so I'd love to find out if I'm wrong.

Your best bet would probably be to create another sprite sheet with the frames reversed and another instance of an AnimatedSprite for that sheet. Then define one or two private IAnimationListeners inside your activity (rather than on the fly when you call .animate()), which alternately detach and attach the two sprites at the end of each animation.

Comment: There is a way where we can manage with one sprite.. I have seen it somewhere before

Comment: Can you please give me more details how I alternately detach and attach two sprites, using an IAnimationListerner in my activity?

Comment: This is too costly. On AndEngine GLES2 you can create an AnimatedSprite from a TiledTextureRegion. In the constructor you pass the loaded ITexture, and a collection of ITextureRegion representing each frame you want to animate in sequence. If you pass frame 1 to last and last to 1 you can achieve your forward/reverse effect just calling sprite.animate(time).

Comment: Are you saying you only need one AnimatedSprite, Rodrigo?

Answer (score 3):

Use [animate](http://srcrr.com/android/AndEngine/GLES1/final/reference/org/andengine/entity/sprite/AnimatedSprite.html#animate%28long%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D,%20int,%20org.andengine.entity.sprite.AnimatedSprite.IAnimationListener%29) method:

```
public AnimatedSprite animate (long[] pFrameDurations, int[] pFrames, 
    int pLoopCount, AnimatedSprite.IAnimationListener pAnimationListener)
```

Animate specifics frames.

Parameters:

`pFrameDurations`   must have the same length as pFrames.

`pFrames`   indices of the frames to animate.

Simply list the indices in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with sprites myself atm and I came across this jQuery plugin. Check it out.
http://spritely.net/